Flutter Secure Storage - Receiveing "Another exception was thrown: Unexpected null value."
I'm developing a new application and testing on Chrome, so I was trying to read a value from the FlutterSecureStorage() object.
Future<String> readJwt() async {
    String? jwt = await _storage.read(key: ConstantUtils.jwt);
    if (jwt == null || jwt.isEmpty) {
      throw EmptyJwtException();
    }
    return jwt;
  }

But everytime I'm receiveing some kind of  exception from a null value inside this operation that blinks an error message on the screen (like on the image below), despite being able to read the jwt value successfully and then the error is gone instantly.


Following is my implementation:
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:sansao_mobile/api/api_response.dart';
import 'package:sansao_mobile/exception/empty_jwt_exception.dart';
import 'package:sansao_mobile/log/logger.dart';
import 'package:sansao_mobile/training/model/training_detail_model.dart';
import 'package:sansao_mobile/training/model/training_reference_model.dart';
import '../utils/constants_util.dart';

class ApiService {
  static const String _apiHost = "localhost:8080";

  final _storage = const FlutterSecureStorage();

  String get _className => "ApiService";
  String get _methodGetTrainingReferences => "getTrainingReferences";
  String get _methodGetTrainingById => "getTrainingById";

  Future<ApiResponse<List<TrainingReference>>> getTrainingReferences() async {
    Logger.logApiRequest(_className, _methodGetTrainingReferences, "");
    String? jwt = await readJwt();
    Uri url = Uri.http(_apiHost, "api/v1/workouts");
    var apiResponse = ApiResponse<List<TrainingReference>>();
    http.Response response;
    try {
      response = await http.get(
        url,
        headers: Map<String, String>.of(
          {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $jwt'},
        ),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      apiResponse.hasError = true;
      apiResponse.error = 'Unknown error.';
      Logger.logApiResponse(
          _className, _methodGetTrainingReferences, e.toString());
      rethrow;
    }

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      apiResponse.body = (json.decode(response.body) as List)
          .map((e) => TrainingReference.fromJson(e))
          .toList();
      Logger.logApiResponse(
          _className, _methodGetTrainingReferences, response.body.toString());
    } else {
      apiResponse.hasError = true;
      apiResponse.error = response.body;
      Logger.logApiNotSuccess(_className, _methodGetTrainingReferences,
          response.statusCode, response.body.toString());
    }
    return apiResponse;
  }

  Future<ApiResponse<TrainingDetail>> getTrainingById(String id) async {
    Logger.logApiRequest(_className, _methodGetTrainingById, id);

    final jwt = await readJwt();
    Uri url = Uri.http(_apiHost, "api/v1/workouts/$id");
    var apiResponse = ApiResponse<TrainingDetail>();
    http.Response response;
    try {
      response = await http.get(url,
          headers: Map.of({HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $jwt'}));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        apiResponse.body = TrainingDetail.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
        Logger.logApiResponse(
            _className, _methodGetTrainingById, response.body.toString());
      } else {
        apiResponse.hasError = true;
        apiResponse.error = response.body;
        Logger.logApiNotSuccess(_className, _methodGetTrainingReferences,
            response.statusCode, response.body.toString());
      }
    } catch (e) {
      apiResponse.hasError = true;
      apiResponse.error = e.toString();
      Logger.logApiResponse(_className, _methodGetTrainingById, e.toString());
      rethrow;
    }

    return apiResponse;
  }

  Future<String> readJwt() async {
    String? jwt = await _storage.read(key: ConstantUtils.jwt);
    if (jwt == null || jwt.isEmpty) {
      throw EmptyJwtException();
    }
    return jwt;
  }
}


pubspec.yaml
name: sansao_mobile
description: "A new Flutter project."
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.2.3 <4.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  http: ^1.1.2
  flutter_secure_storage: ^9.2.2


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
[Visualization of the erron on the screen][1]


"I'm receiveing some kind of exception from a null value inside this operation" Please edit your question to show the exact error message and its stack trace.

is it always return null or just first time you call read() ?

@puf-FrankvanPuffelen there is no staktrace. It only shows that on console: "Another exception was thrown: Unexpected null value." I can't even catch the exception.

@Lightn1ng always returns null.
